# HttpClient ignores headers passed to .get()

Tags: angular

Not a duplicate: [Angular HTTPClient ignores headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55113269/angular-httpclient-ignores-headers). This issue was solved by including a `body` parameter, which does not exist with `.get()`. The `options` parameter is correctly set, from what I can tell.

As the title says, I'm trying to use `HttpClient.get()`, but I get errors. Here's the method call:

```js
private search(): Observable<Blob.IClientData[]> {
  const url =
    environment.origin + environment.baseUrl + '/search/' + this.query;
  const retrieved = new Date();
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': environment.origin,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    Allow: 'GET',
    Accept: '*/*',
  });

  return this._http.get<Blob.IClientData[]>(url, { headers: headers }).pipe(
    map((response: Blob.IResponseBody[]) => {
      console.log(response);
      const results: Blob.IClientData[] = response.map(
        (body: Blob.IResponseBody) => {
          const clientData: Blob.IClientData = {
            id: body['id'],
            word: body['word'],
            descriptor: body['descriptor'],
            partSpeech: body['partSpeech'],
            tense: body['tense'],
            icon: body['icon'],
            md5: body['md5'],
            retrieved: retrieved,
          };

          return clientData;
        }
      );

      return results;
    })
  );
}
```

And the console errors:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/api/v0-alpha/search/query. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/api/v0-alpha/search/query. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:8000/api/v0-alpha/search/query", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8000/api/v0-alpha/search/query: 0 Unknown Error", error: error }
core.js:6456
```

It says But I did define it!

According to [Jota.Toledo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45286959/2858094) on [Adding a HTTP header to the Angular HttpClient doesn't send the header, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/adding-a-http-header-to-the-angular-httpclient-doesnt-send-the-header-why), one option of defining headers to be passed to `HttpClient` is as follows (this is the construct I use):

```js
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'h1':'v1','h2':'v2'});
```

I know that `url` is being constructed properly, as the error messages point to the right address (http://localhost:8000/api/v0-alpha/search/query). Execution never reaches the `console.log()` statement because there is no response, so changing things inside `pipe()` won't help at this stage.

What else can I try?

**Update**

*environment.ts*

```js
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  origin: 'http://localhost:8000',
  baseUrl: '/api/v0-alpha',
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response header**, not a request header (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin): you should configure CORS appropriately on your back-end, so that it permits cross-origin requests (the browser will made a pre-flight request just to check that).

Also, apparently, you are accessing your app from an origin which is not the one of your API (`http://localhost:8000`): if you are still prototyping and do not want to deal with CORS on your back-end, you may just want to run everything from the same origin (protocol + host + port).

Comment: How do I use the same host in a development environment? I have Django running at port `8000` and Angular at `8100`. If I try to use the same port, something won't run.

Comment: I followed [How to enable CORS headers in your Django Project?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-enable-cors-headers-in-your-django-project/) but I still see the errors.

Comment: Resetting both servers after updating CORS in the Django project was all I needed.